# Working stored procedure fails when called from SQL Agent Job

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-agent-job

I have a stored procedure that runs fine with no errors inside SQL Server Management Studio. However, when the same stored procedure is executed as a step of a SQL Agent Job, it terminates with:

> **Error 3930:** The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

The stored procedure lives in a schema named `[Billing]`.  Most of the tables it uses are also in the `[Billing]` schema.

The main stored procedure begins a database transaction.  The stored procedures called by the main stored procedure do all of their work on that inherited transaction.  The main stored procedure is responsible for committing or rolling back the transaction.

The database User running the SQL Agent Job Step is not in the Sysadmin role, nor is it dbo.  It belongs to the db_datareader and db_datawriter database roles, and has been given Delete, Execute, Insert, References, Select, and Update, permissions in the `[Billing]` schema.

Here is the main stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Billing].[GenerateBillXml]
  @pUseProductionPsSystem bit
  ,@pPeriodYear int
  ,@pPeriodMonthNumber int
  ,@pDocumentTypeName varchar(20)
  ,@pUser varchar(100)
  ,@pFilePath varchar(500)
  ,@pExportDateTime datetime2(7)
  ,@pResultCode int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SET @pResultCode = 0;

  DECLARE @transactionBegun bit = 0
          ,@RC int = 0
          ,@processDateTimeUtc datetime2(7) = GETUTCDATE()
          ,@billGenerationId int
          ,@PsJobSuffix char(2)
          ,@periodDate date
          ,@periodDateString char(6)
          ,@PsBaseJobNumber char(6)
          ,@okayToRun int = 0
          ,@msg varchar(500);

  BEGIN TRY
    /* calculate the period date */
    SET @periodDate = CONVERT(date,CAST(@pPeriodMonthNumber as varchar) + '/01/' + CAST(@pPeriodYear as varchar))
    SET @periodDateString = CONVERT(varchar, @periodDate, 12); -- yyMMdd

    /* retrieve the job suffix */
    SELECT @PsJobSuffix = CAST([PsJobSuffix] as char(2))
      FROM [dbo].[DocumentType] dt
      WHERE [Name] like @pDocumentTypeName;

    /* build the base job number */
    SET @PsBaseJobNumber = LEFT(@periodDateString, 4) + @PsJobSuffix

    /*
     * We've made it past the input check - record the fact that we're generating a bill
     */
    INSERT [Billing].[BillGeneration] (
      [PsBaseJobNumber], [Status], [RunBy], [ProcessDateTimeUtc]
    ) VALUES (
      @PsBaseJobNumber, 'Running', @pUser, @processDateTimeUtc
    );

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
      SET @billGenerationId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    EXECUTE @RC = [Billing].[_0_OkayToGenerateBill]
      @PsBaseJobNumber
      ,@okayToRun OUTPUT
      ,@pResultCode OUTPUT;

    IF @pResultCode = 0  
    BEGIN
      -- called stored procedure completed without error
      IF @okayToRun = -1 -- this bill has already been generated
      BEGIN
        SET @msg = 'The billing for job ' + CAST(@PsBaseJobNumber as varchar) + ' has already been produced.';
        RAISERROR(@msg, 16, 1)
      END

      IF @okayToRun = -2 -- too early to run billing for this period
      BEGIN
        SET @msg = 'It is too early to generate billing for job ' + CAST(@PsBaseJobNumber as varchar) + '.';
        RAISERROR(@msg, 16, 1)
      END

      IF @okayToRun <> 1 -- unknown error...
      BEGIN
        SET @msg = 'Unknown error occured while determining whether okay to generate bill for job ' + CAST(@PsBaseJobNumber as varchar) + '.';
        RAISERROR(@msg, 16, 1)
      END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @msg = 'Unknown failure in sub-stored procedure [Billing].[_0_OkayToRun]() for job ' + CAST(@PsBaseJobNumber as varchar) + '.';
      RAISERROR(@msg, 16, 1)  -- will cause branch to CATCH
    END

    /* Okay to generate bill */

    /* If not in a transaction, begin one */
    IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
      BEGIN TRANSACTION
      SET @transactionBegun = 1;
    END

    EXECUTE @RC = [Billing].[_1_GeneratePsPreBillData] 
       @PsBaseJobNumber
      ,@pUser
      ,@pResultCode OUTPUT;

    IF @pResultCode = 0
    BEGIN
      -- stored proced ran to successful completion
      EXECUTE @RC = [Billing].[_2_GetBillingDataForXmlGeneration]
         @pUseProductionPsSystem
        ,@PsBaseJobNumber
        ,@pResultCode OUTPUT;

      IF @pResultCode = 0
      BEGIN
        -- stored proced ran to successful completion
        IF @transactionBegun = 1
          -- all table data has been created/updated
          COMMIT TRANSACTION

        -- Output XML bill to file
        EXECUTE @RC = [Billing].[_3_GenerateBillingXmlFilesForPsJob] 
           @PsBaseJobNumber
          ,@pFilePath
          ,@pExportDateTime
          ,@pResultCode OUTPUT;

        IF @pResultCode <> 0
        BEGIN
          -- called stored procedure failed
          SET @msg = '[Billing].[_3_GenerateBillingXmlFilesForPsJob]() failed for job ' + CAST(@PsBaseJobNumber as varchar);
          RAISERROR(@msg, 16, 1)  -- will cause branch to CATCH
        END
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
        -- called stored procedure failed
        SET @msg = '[Billing].[_2_GetBillingDataForXmlGeneration]() failed for job ' + CAST(@PsBaseJobNumber as varchar);
        RAISERROR(@msg, 16, 1)  -- will cause branch to CATCH
      END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- called stored procedure failed
      SET @msg = '[Billing].[_1_GeneratePsPreBillData]() failed for job ' + CAST(@PsBaseJobNumber as varchar);
      RAISERROR(@msg, 16, 1)  -- will cause branch to CATCH
    END

    -- bill generation was successful
    IF @billGenerationId IS NOT NULL
      UPDATE [Billing].[BillGeneration]
        SET [Status] = 'Successful', [ProcessEndDateTimeUtc] = GETUTCDATE()
        WHERE [Id] = @billGenerationId;

  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    -- rollback transaction if we started one
    IF @transactionBegun = 1
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    -- record the error
    INSERT [Billing].[BillGenerationError] (
      [DateTime], [Object], [ErrorNumber], [ErrorMessage]
    ) VALUES (
      GETDATE(), OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID), ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE()
    );

    -- bill generation failed
    IF @billGenerationId IS NOT NULL
      UPDATE [Billing].[BillGeneration]
        SET [Status] = 'Failed'
            ,[Note] = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            ,[ProcessEndDateTimeUtc] = GETUTCDATE()
        WHERE [Id] = @billGenerationId;

    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() as ErrorNumber;
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;
    SET @pResultCode = 1
  END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Do you use any file operation inside subroutines or `sp_xml_preparedocument`? It looks like permission problem.

Comment: No.  However the last stored procedure to be called, `[_3_GenerateBillingXmlFilesForPsJob]`, uses `EXEC xp_cmdshell ` calling BCP.exe with a query to pull data and then write it to a file.  I've checked to make sure that the account of the User running the stored procedure has Modify privileges on that folder.

Comment: So we have it. Your SQL Agent account have not access. You could create proxy account.

Comment: I tested this by logging into the machine with the domain account of the database user and running the stored procedure, successfully, directly in SQL Server Management Studio.  All files were created successfully.

Comment: Did you run SSMS on the same user/account  as the SQL Server Agent uses?

Comment: No, as that 's a managed domain service account. When a SQL Agent Job Step has a User specified in its "Run as user" setting, does it not execute in that user's context?

Comment: In addition to permissions, try running the proc from SSMS session with `SET ARITHABORT OFF` to see if it reproduces the error. SQL Server Agent is notorious for not setting all [the magic 7 session options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views) properly, which are required for some features.

Comment: Thanks, @DanGuzman for the suggestion - I appreciate it.  It turned out that when `BCP.EXE` was executed, it was running under the service account that supports SQL Agent, which in this instance was "Local System", which didn't have the privilege needed.  My solution to this issue appears in my answer, below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lukasz Szozda hinted in one of his comments to my question, the issue was that when the SQL Agent job executed the `BCP.EXE` command, it was running under the service account used by SQL Agent, which for me is the fairly restrictive "Local System" account.  At this point it became obvious to me that a Proxy account had to be used.  So I created a Proxy under `Operating System (CmdExec)`, which was the only choice that made sense.

I went back to the job step to change it to use the Proxy, but then noticed that in its current type of `Transact-SQL script (TSQL)`, there is no way to assign a Proxy account.

After trying a few things, finally decided to put the TSQL statements that were in the job step into a new stored procedure, and then call that stored procedure from the SQL command-line executable `SQLCMD.EXE`.  I then changed the job step type from `Transact-SQL script (TSQL)` to `Operating System (CmdExec)`. I could then set the `Run As` field to the Proxy I created earlier. I specified the command to run as `CMD.EXE /c SQLCMD.EXE -S [ServerName] -Q "EXEC [NewProcedureName] [parameters]"`.

If you're curious as to why I'm running `SQLCMD.EXE` under `CMD.EXE`, it's because one of the parameters to the new stored procedure was the current date in a particular format (`'%date:~4,10%'`), which the SQL Server job execution environment didn't support, but which `CMD.EXE` certainly does.

Overall, I think this took a bit more effort than I expected.